# How to change android UI elements tint dynamically for the entire app?

Tags: android, themes

How can I change the background tint color of UI elements(TextView, 
Spinner, etc ...) dynamically for the entire app. Something in terms of *colorAccent* , can it be changed dynamically

Comment: [MultipleThemeMaterialDesign](https://github.com/pratikbutani/MultipleThemeMaterialDesign)

Answer (score 0):

You should define multiple themes and in OnCreate of each activity, before calling 'super.onCreate()' and 'setContentView()' method, you should choose your desired Theme.